# Maximize imported image on page in officer / officedown to Word (docx)

Tags: r-markdown, officer

I recently tried using [`officedown`](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) to create a .docx report of my document. In my documents I import images from an `\images` folder in my project directory.

Normally when I knit a document I am able to maximize its position on the page.
Does anyone know how to do this using `officedown`? I have no issues when I run this code in RMarkdown

**This is what I get using officedown**
[image: Here is what I get]

**This is what I want (notice the image is taking up the whole page)**
[image: Here is what I want]

I have included a reprex below

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author:
title: "GitHub Example"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
pacman::p_load(readxl, dplyr, apastats, officedown, officer, ggplot2, knitr) # load packages

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center',
                      fig.cap = TRUE,
                      fig.pos = 'H',
                      fig.path = 'images/',
                      echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      include = TRUE,
                      out.height="100%",  out.width="100%",
                      dpi = 300)

```

```{r}
# Creating a boxplot and saving it in \images directory
plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
ggsave("images/plot.png",plot, width=11, height=8.5, dpi=300)

```

## Figures 

Figure \@ref(fig:boxplot) shows a boxplot that is made within the RMarkdown document. 
I want to call in an image saved from a previous R scripts which is saved 
in my `\images` directory shown in Figure \@ref(fig:plot). But notice how it 
does not take up the whole page.

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->
```{r fig.cap="A boxplot", fig.id = "boxplot"}
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->


<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->

```{r fig.id="plot", fig.cap="boxplot imported from images folder", echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("images/plot.png")
``` 

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips for working with plots/figures in Word output:
a) you need to use `fig.height` and/or `fig.width` to scale plots/figures;
b) consider using chunk option `crop = TRUE` with the function `hook_pdfcrop()` to trim/[crop](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/crop-plot.html) the extra white margin around the plot (see @CL. SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711823/knitr-rmd-word-document-control-details-of-figures));
c) chunk options: `fig.align`, `fig.pos`, `out.height`, `out.width` or `out.extra` are not supported for Word output.

To achieve desired output, you may consider the following changes:

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
pacman::p_load(readxl, dplyr, apastats, officedown, officer, ggplot2, knitr) # load packages

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.cap = TRUE,
                      fig.path = 'images/',
                      echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      include = TRUE,
                      dpi = 300)
```
````

````
```{r}
# Creating a boxplot and saving it in \images directory
plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
ggsave("images/plot.png", plot, dpi = 300)
```
````

````
```{r fig.id = "plot", fig.cap = "boxplot imported from images folder", fig.height = 6, fig.width = 7.5, echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("images/plot.png")
```
````

Does this helps somehow?

Comment: This is perfect and good advice. I suppose I was just looking for something that would maximize the size of the image relative to the page in a similar fashion to `out.width` and `out.height`. Thank you very much for your answer it was helpful in getting things to work

Comment: fig.align is supported by officedown

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, David.

Comment: @DavidGohel, what about fig.pos?  I found nothing regarding figure placement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `knitr` usual parameters `fig.width` and `fig.height` (inches).

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author:
title: "GitHub Example"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
pacman::p_load(readxl, dplyr, apastats, officedown, officer, ggplot2, knitr) # load packages

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center',
                      echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      dpi = 300)

```

```{r}
plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```



<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->
```{r fig.cap="A boxplot", fig.id = "boxplot"}
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=5, fig.id="plot", fig.cap="boxplot imported from images folder", echo=FALSE}
plot
``` 

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks David Gohel for your answer! Really love this package.

Answer (score 1):

After implementing @David Gohel answer for a few projects. I still am envious of the use of `out.height` and `out.width` in PDF outputs.

In most of my projects I have resorted to going into File Explorer, right clicking on the figure in question and writing down the images dimensions to calculate its aspect ratio.
[image]

In a typical `officedown` project I will only call `fig.width` so that I can make sure the figure is maximized to the size of the page **while** maintaining its original aspect ratio.

```
knitr::include_graphics("images/plot.png")
```

I worked on trying to implement this automatically which would require reading the images dimensions to set `fig.asp`. Its not perfect, and I am sure someone else will have a much better and cleaner approach but you can accomplish this using the `magick` package. This also requires 2 chunks to accomplish the feat (again not optimal)

```
{r, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
# First chunk to fetch the image size and calculate its aspect ratio
img <- magick::image_read("images/plot1.png") # read the image using the magic library

img.asp <- image_info(img)$height / image_info(img)$width # calculate the figures aspect ratio
```

```
{r fig.width=11, fig.asp = img.asp, fig.id="plot", fig.cap="boxplot imported from images folder", echo=FALSE}
# second chunk uses "img.asp" to make sure our aspect ratio is maintained.
knitr::include_graphics("images/plot.png")
```