# How to import a figure as its original height/width ratio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I'm using the `officedown` package to generate a Word document. May I ask, if I want to import a well-designed figure from the disk, how to control `officedown` not to change the height/width ratio of the figure?

For example, my original figure looks like this:

[image]

However, in the Word document generated by `officedown`, it looks like this:

[image]

May I ask, how to avoid the distortion in `officedown`? And how to make the width of the figure take the whole line?

My question can be reproduced by the following code:

````
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    fig.cap = TRUE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE
)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
```

```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("the file path to a figure")
```
````

Your kind guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799018/maximize-imported-image-on-page-in-officer-officedown-to-word-docx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @VishalA. I tried the method in that question but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experimented a little.

For the output:

```
bookdown::word_document2
```

... I haven't found any solution.

But for the

```
officedown::rdocx_document
```

... construction

````
```{r fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
knitr::include_graphics("xxx.png") 
```
````

... works without any problems.

---

**An addition:**

*It should work for your task:*

````
```{r}
library(imager)
my_pic <- load.image("xxx.png")
asp_rat <- dim(my_pic)[2]/dim(my_pic)[1] #find our aspect ratio

```

```{r fig.asp = asp_rat, fig.height = ??, fig.width = ??} #choose the best for your pic
knitr::include_graphics("xxx.png") 
```
````

[image]

Look, the aspect ratio is saved. You should only determinate fig.height/width for the each case. I haven't any ideas yet...

Comment: Thanks, @manro. Yes, `fig.width=5` and `fig.height=5` can change the figure size. However, when I import a figure from outside, I don't know the exact height/width ratio of the figure. If I set `fig.width=X` and `fig.height=Y`, the figure could not be imported as it is.

Comment: @Xiaochi From outside? What is it? An external document with pictures?

Comment: Hello @manro, "from outside" just means the figure is imported from the disk, not generated in the current R environment. To be clearer, I modified the question, please have a look. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Xiaochi Look, I corrected my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, @manro.The figure would still be changed. I think `fig.asp=1` means setting `height/width = 1`, which is going to make the figure become a square.

Comment: @Xiaochi Look to an addition

Comment: This method works perfectly! Thank you so much for your kind guidance, @manro.

Comment: If you have access to a Linux system with the `identify` tool installed you can do this without the `imager` package like this: `as.numeric(strsplit(system("identify -format '%wx%h\n' fig/xxx.png", intern = TRUE), split="x")[[1]][1]) /
  as.numeric(strsplit(system("identify -format '%wx%h\n' xxx.png", intern = TRUE), split="x")[[1]][2])`